# Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement Python(Mysql)

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to do sql mstatement and can not understand what am i doing wrong. I have 3 tables:

[1st one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUW89.png)

[2nd one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHMtu.png)

[3rd one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdcVt.png)

i need to form exel file like:

| id | name     | secname   | surname | test | result |  date_time             |
| 1  | Ardella  | Victoire  | Phoenix |Test1 |  5+    |  7/20/2004  10:00:00 PM |

```
users_from_cur_depart = sql.read_sql(
            ('SELECT users.Name, users.Secname, users.Surname, tests.Name, results.Result, results.curdate FROM'
             ' users JOIN results  ON users.chatId = results.chatId JOIN tests ON results.testId = tests.id'), self.connection)
```

and everything work fine with multi-statement, but I need to collect data about those users who have a certain value in field 'otdel'(means department btw). And this condition breaks everything

```
users_from_cur_depart = sql.read_sql(
            ('SELECT users.Name, users.Secname, users.Surname, tests.Name, results.Result, results.curdate FROM'
             ' users JOIN results  ON users.chatId = results.chatId JOIN tests ON results.testId = tests.id WHERE users.otdel = %(value)s'),
            self.connection,
            params={'value', depart_id})
```

Get an error:

```
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT users.Name, users.Secname, users.Surname, 
tests.Name, results.Result, results.curdate FROM users JOIN results  ON users.chatId = results.chatId JOIN tests ON 
results.testId = tests.id WHERE users.otdel = %(value)s': 
Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

Can smb help me and explain what is wrong please?

Comment: Typo: `{'value', depart_id}` should be `{'value': depart_id}`

Comment: @Barmar omg, thank you, my eyes just dead after 10h coding didn't see it